# Service worker only fetches url from cache when adding "index.html"

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, page-refresh

I use a serviceworker to serve content offline. The following code works well except when I refresh the page in offline mode right after opening and installing the serviceworker in online-mode.
All these scenarios work:
    1. Loading the page online, refreshing the page onlinge -> refreshing the page offline - works.
    2. Loading "/offline-test/" online -> loading "/offline-test/index.html" offline - works
    3. Loading "/offline-test/index.html/ online -> loading "/offline-test/" offline - works
Only this scenario isn't working:
Loading the page online -> refresh the page in offline-mode.

Why?

I'm using Chrome Dev tools to simulate Offline-Mode. Same problem in Firefox (turning WiFi off after loading the page).

index.html

```html
<HTML>
...
<BODY>
...
</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('../sw.js')
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("Service Worker Registered");
                });
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

sw.js

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
//  self.skipWaiting();

    if(navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('Navigator is online');
        e.waitUntil(caches.keys()
            .then(function(keyList) {
                console.log('Try to delete cache.');
                return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
                    return caches.delete(key)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            console.log('Cache-Key '+key+' will be deleted');
                            return response;
                        }, function(reject) {
                            consoloe.log('Failure deleting '+key);
                            return reject;
                        });
                }))
            })
        );
    }

    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open('offline-test-v3').then(function(cache) {
            console.log('index.html and all the others will be added to cache');
            return cache.addAll([
                'offline-test/',
                'offline-test/index.html',
                'offline-test/style.css',
                'offline-test/logo-192.png',
                'offline-test/fonts/ROCK.TTF',
                'manifest.json',
                'offline-test/favicon.ico'
            ])
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log('Everything succesfully added to cache');
                });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(ev) {
//  ev.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
//  clients.claim();
//  ev.waitUntil(clients.claim());
    console.log('I\'m activated');
});

self.addEventListener('update', function(eve) {
    console.log('I\'m updated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Will fetch '+event.request.url);
    //Networ first
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
            console.log('Try to fetch '+event.request.url+' from cache');
            return caches.match(event.request);
        })
    );
```

console after loading index.html online

```
Service Worker Registered
sw.js:9 Navigator is online
sw.js:12 Try to delete cache.
sw.js:29 index.html and all the others will be added to cache
sw.js:40 Everything succesfully added to cache
sw.js:58 I'm activated
```

console after refreshing in offline-mode

```
Will fetch index.html
sw.js:70 Try to fetch [url]/index.html from cache
The FetchEvent for [url]/index.html" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by adding the new cache as a resolve to the preceding cache-deleting-routine.
Probably the two threads conflicted.

New sw.js

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {  
    if(navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('Navigator is online');
        e.waitUntil(caches.keys()
        .then(function(keyList) {
            console.log('Try to delete cache.');
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
                return caches.delete(key)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log('Cache-Key '+key+' will be deleted');
                        return response;
                    }, function(reject) {
                        consoloe.log('Failure deleting '+key);
                        return reject;
                    });
            }))
        })
        .then(function() {
            caches.open('offline-test-v3').then(function(cache) {
                console.log('index.html and all the others will be added to cache');
                return cache.addAll([
                    'offline-test/',
                    'offline-test/index.html',
                    'offline-test/style.css',
                    'offline-test/logo-192.png',
                    'offline-test/fonts/ROCK.TTF',
                    'manifest.json',
                    'offline-test/favicon.ico'
                ])
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log('Everything succesfully added to cache');
                });
            })
        }));
    }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(ev) {
    console.log('I\'m activated');
});

self.addEventListener('update', function(eve) {
    console.log('I\'m updated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Will fetch '+event.request.url);
    //Network first
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request)
            .then(function(resolve) {
                console.log('Fetched '+event.request.url+' via the browser way.');
                return resolve;
            }, function(reject) {
                console.log('Try to fetch '+event.request.url+' via the serviceworker way');
                return caches.match(event.request);
            })
        );
/*  if(!navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('Try to fetch '+event.request.url+' from cache.');
        event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
        );
    }*/

});
```